# Get first item in list from linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I wish to get just the very first record I realize the the "Take() will not work.

So I have a List that queries another list

```
List<string> etchList = new List<string>();
etchList.Add("709");
```

The Linq query is

```
var query = (from vio in AddPlas
            where etchList.Any(vioID => vio.Key.Formatted.Equals(vioID))
            select new
            {
                EtchVectors = vio.Shapes
            }).ToList().Take(1);
```

Now this "Take(1)" will only work if I had other data in etchList,  so it is not what I am looking for.  The results I'm getting look like this:

Formatted
"clinesegs" 1013.98 5142.96 "LYR3_SIG2"
"clinesegs" 1020.16 5168.33 "LYR3_SIG2"
"clinesegs" 967.03 5151.31 "LYR3_SIG2"
"clinesegs" 971.43 5174.01 "LYR3_SIG2"

I wish to ONLY get back the first "row in the list of

```
"clinesegs" 1013.98 5142.96 "LYR3_SIG2"
```

EDIT:

Ok this code exist:

```
public class AddPla
{
public AddPla()
{
    Shapes = new List<Parse>();
}

public Parse Key { get; set; }
public Parse Pla { get; set; }
public Parse Angle { get; set; }
public Parse Default { get; set; }
public List<Parse> Shapes { get; set; }
public Parse DoubleBrace { get; set; }
public Parse Number1 { get; set; }
public Parse Number2 { get; set; }
  }

  public class Parse
  {

public string Formatted { get; set; }
public string Original { get; set; }

  }
```

Then this List

```
  var AddPlas = new List<AddPla>();
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to "hide" any code,  I just didn't post originally thinking it was not that important,  but you see how Shapes is a List<Parse> type

Comment: So, hold on, you want to get the first `Shapes` from each `AddPla`?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't suppose it's as easy as [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx)?

If you expect that your query will not return any results, use [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)

**Update**

If what you are asking for is "Get the first `Shapes` from each `AddPla`", then add the `First` to your `select` statement, rather than at the end

```
select new { EtchVectors = vio.Shapes.First() }
```

Comment: Or `FirstOrDefault()` if it should *not* throw.

Comment: First and FirstOrDefault both give me all 4 still  Formatted
"clinesegs" 1013.98 5142.96 "LYR3_SIG2"
"clinesegs" 1020.16 5168.33 "LYR3_SIG2"
"clinesegs" 967.03 5151.31 "LYR3_SIG2"
"clinesegs" 971.43 5174.01 "LYR3_SIG2"

Comment: @ChrisHamilton, yes, please update your post with your new findings.

Answer (score 5):

You can try with [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb340482.aspx).

```
var query = (from vio in AddPlas
            where etchList.Any(vioID => vio.Key.Formatted.Equals(vioID))
            select new
            {
                EtchVectors = vio.Shapes
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: No need to call `ToList()`, `FirstOrDefault()` can operate on the raw `IEnumerable<T>` just fine.

Comment: still get all 4   Formatted
"clinesegs" 1013.98 5142.96 "LYR3_SIG2"
"clinesegs" 1020.16 5168.33 "LYR3_SIG2"
"clinesegs" 967.03 5151.31 "LYR3_SIG2"
"clinesegs" 971.43 5174.01 "LYR3_SIG2"

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`FistOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) method to safely return the first item from your query, or `null` if the query returned no results:

```
var result =
    (from vio in AddPlas
     where etchList.Any(vioID => vio.Key.Formatted.Equals(vioID))
     select new
     {
        EtchVectors = vio.Shapes.FistOrDefault()
     })
```

Or equivalently:

```
var result = AddPlas.Where(x => etchList.Any(y => x.Key.Formatted.Equals(y)))
                    .Select(x => new { EtchVectors = x.Shapes.FistOrDefault() });
```

Comment: @ChrisHamilton Sorry, I didn't see your updated question. I've updated my answer to match your latest specs.